# Cheerio errors at runtime when built using rollup, dependency resolution seems to be the issue

Tags: cheerio, rollup, rollupjs

Hi I've been trying to use cheerio in my node library and found this error, i've narrowed it down to rollup not correctly getting the dependency other then that I'm at a loss

enviroment

- OS macOS Mojave Version 10.14.3
- Node v11.4.0
- Rollup 1.6.0
- Cheerio 1.0.0-rc.2

repo with error https://github.com/lukecollier/cheerio-rollup-problems

i get a stack trace with

```
util.js:307
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('superCtor', 'Function', superCtor);
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "superCtor" argument must be of type Function. Received type undefined
    at inherits (util.js:307:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/collierl/Project/Learn/cheerio-rollup-problem/index.js:10575:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:560:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:552:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:12)
    at executeUserCode (internal/bootstrap/node.js:342:17)
    at startExecution (internal/bootstrap/node.js:276:5)
```

when I look into the output javascript it seems that it's a rollup error not adding the right dependencies but I want to make sure I'm not missing something before opening a issue

Comment: Is rollup a frontend thing? If so you want jQuery instead.

Comment: No rollup is a tool for bundling javascript efficiently! (https://rollupjs.org/guide/en)
In this case I'm using it for bundling a node library but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I am running into this as well. Did you ever figure it out, Luke?

Comment: same here :( did not find any solution

Comment: Was able to work around this issue by changing the rollup config as suggested here: https://github.com/rollup/rollup/issues/1507#issuecomment-340550539